# Using JSON_VALUE for parse column in SQL Server table

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I have never worked with JSON in SQL Server before that's why need some help.

I have written a simple snippet of code:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @json = 
N'{
  
   "id":"40476",
   "tags":[
      {
         "id":"5f5883",          
      },
      {
         "id":"5fc8",
 }
   ],
   "type":"student",
   "external_id":"40614476"
}'


SELECT
    JSON_value(@json, '$.tags[0].id') as tags
```

In sample above I write code how get first "id" from "tags".

But how looks like script if in "tags" not 2 "id", but an unknown number this "id" and result should be in column like this:

```
 1    5f5883  
 2    5fc8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `OPENJSON()` with explicit schema to parse the `$.tags` JSON array:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @json = 
N'{
   "id":"40476",
   "tags":[
      {
         "id":"5f5883"          
      },
      {
         "id":"5fc8"
      }
   ],
   "type":"student",
   "external_id":"40614476"
}'

SELECT id
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.tags') WITH (id varchar(10) '$.id')
```

Result:

```
id
------
5f5883
5fc8
```

If you want to get the index of each `id` in the `$.tags` JSON array, then you need a combination of `OPENJSON()` with default schema and `JSON_VALUE()`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(int, [key]) AS rn, JSON_VALUE([value], '$.id') AS id
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.tags')
```

Result:

```
rn  id
----------
0   5f5883
1   5fc8
```

Comment: Added note, *if* the column you define within the `WITH` clause has the same name as the entity in the JSON, you don't need to define the entity. So `WITH (id varchar(10))` would be sufficient here.

Comment: @Larnu, I agree, I just usually use the full syntax. And if I remember correctly, in this case the match is case sensitive.

Comment: It is case sensitive, yes.

Comment: Thanks it is work:)
But if this json in table columns, I`m trying 
SELECT id
FROM OPENJSON((select ENTITY from dbo.test), '$.tags') WITH (id varchar(10) '$.id')

but got error:  Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

When try 

select  EnData.[id] from 
 dbo.test q  CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (q.tags) as EnData 

got error too

Comment: @Zhorov select *, tt.id, tt.date from dbo.Test q CROSS APPLY OPENJSON ( ENTITY, 'lax $.tags') WITH (id varchar(max) '$.id') as tt it is help me) Thank you

Answer (score -1):

```sql
select I.id
from openjson(@json)
with(
tags nvarchar(max) '$.tags' as JSON ) M
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(M.tags)
WITH (
ID Varchar(20) '$.id'
) as I;
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?